# Error when opening GeoMondrian schema file and using MDX query in GeoMondrian Workbench

Tags: postgis, java, spatial-analysis

I'm having trouble using the GeoMondrian Workbench on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system. I've followed the installation instructions and have installed the following:

- Oracle Java 8
- PostgreSQL 9.5
- PostGIS 2.5

I've downloaded the GeoMondrian Workbench and the "simple_geofoodmart.sql" file, created a database, and passed the necessary parameters to the workbench.

[image]

However, when I try to open the "simple_geofoodmart.xml" schema file, I get the following error:

> Error: Schema file /home/tarik/workbench/demo/simple_geofoodmart.xml is invalid. org/opengis/referencing/NoSuchAuthorityCodeException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opengis/referencing/NoSuchAuthorityCodeException

Additionally, when I try to use an MDX query, I get the following error:

> "Exception in thread 'AWT-EventQueue-0' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class mondrian.olap.fun.GlobalFunTable at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchema$RolapSchemaFunctionTable.defineFunctions(RolapSchema.java:1643)"

I've tried to resolve all the dependencies and have made sure that I have the necessary JAR files in my classpath, but I'm still getting the same errors. What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5 reached end-of-life over two years ago. And this workbench application is a decade old (5 years older than the OS release). Your software stack is not ideally situated for stability.

Comment: the problem is that there are articles that were published in 2020 and 2021 which used this tool, and it is the only open-source tools which does what it does, but if you know alternatives i''d be happy to know about it

Comment: by using these versions i wanted to recreate an environment that was used for the same purpose